# Property file load

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a web application that reads content from a property file. When will this property file be loaded into memory. ie. Once I deploy the application with some content in the prop file, and after deployment , I change the contents of the prop file, will the changes be reflected or do I have to redeploy?

**EDIT :** An accessor class' static block reads content from the property file, which is a part of a deployed web application. Now after deployment, i change the property file contents. Will the accessor class read the changes or will it take up the old values?

**EDIT2 :** when the class is reloaded, will it surely take up the new modified file or rather take up the file cached during deployment(if at all it is cached)

Comment: Is there any framwork (struts or something)?

Comment: I'm assuming this is in regards to some web framework - not just using properties files in a general web app.  Please edit your question to state what framework this is in regards to.

Comment: This is a general web app using web services

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the property file is being loaded by the Properties class, then the property file will be loaded once when the Properties#load() method is called. It will not automatically be reloaded unless your application specifically supports reloading or if your web container restarts the web application during hot deployment.

update: Since the property file is loaded in a static initializer, then the property file will be reloaded when the class is reloaded (e.g. when the web app is hot deployed). If you want to debug this, a simple println() in the static initializer will show you when this happens.

Comment: Ya, thats correct. But what was confusing was that , when the class is reloaded, will it surely take up the new modified file or rather take up the file cached during deployment(if at all it is cached)

Comment: If you are holding a reference to a Properties object in a class variable (static) then it will be garbage collected when the class is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the app server - generally, you'd have to redeploy.  But some app servers, in certain configurations may monitor files and kick off a redeploy when they detect file changes. (as an example - I believe Tomcat will automatically redeploy when it detects file changes in exploded deployments.)

Answer (score 0):

If this file is loaded by your class than I am pretty sure it won't reload it by it self.

If I were you I would have a separate thread that in given time intervals wakes up, checks whether the file modification date has changed and if it did than reloads it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Configuration provides [automatic reloading/saving](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#Automatic_Reloading) of file-based configurations.